# Evaluate $\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(\ln t)}{t}$

Tags: calculus, limits

We know that 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(t)}{t}=1.
\end{equation}
I was wondering what would be 
\begin{equation}
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{\sin(\ln t)}{t}.
\end{equation}
I tried using L'hospital's rule, but I am not getting anywhere with that. Any help will be deeply acknowledged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may choose $t_{n}>0$ such that $t_{n}\rightarrow 0$ and that $\ln t_{n}=-2n\pi+\pi/6$, then $\sin(\ln t_{n})=1/2$ and hence the limit is $\infty$.

On the other hand, if you choose $s_{n}>0$ such that $s_{n}\rightarrow 0$ and that $\ln s_{n}=-2n\pi$, then $\sin(\ln s_{n})=0$, the limit is $0$.

The limit does not exist in the extended real sense.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:**
  Put $t = e^x$.

Also, notice L.H.L doesn't exist

Comment: What is L.H.L. please?

Comment: @saulspatz when t<0 $\ln t$ is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The limit does not exist as @saulspatz said because ln(x) is not defined for x<0 and x=0. That's what we call Left Hand Limit. However, you might be interested in computing the RHL if it exists. @user284331 explained that by choosing distinct specific sequences of real numbers, say t_n, you may obtain different values when calculating the limit. This contradicts the uniqueness of the limit and the RHL thus does not exist.